# How to make sum for negative number and positive numbers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I am getting json data from server through $http.get method. in the data one of the field called Credits, it contains negative values and positive numbers. any one can help me how can i get negative numbers in seperate total and positive numbers in separate totals??

```
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
        total += parseInt(this[i][prop])
    }
    return total
}
$scope.totalCreadit = function (arr) {
    return arr.sum("credits");
}
```

this function is giving me the totals but i need to separate in total for negative values and positive values.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want `totalCreadit` to return in this case?

Comment: Just wondering how can this function work.Here `arr` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method,

```js
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, 23, -1, -13, 10, -52 ],
    positive = arr.filter(function (a) { return a >= 0; }),
    negative = arr.filter(function (a) { return a < 0; }),
    sumnegative = negative.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }),
    sumpositive = positive.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; });
console.log(sumnegative);
console.log(sumpositive);
```